# No records are created on Docker Container (Testcontainers + Database Rider + MyBatis)

Tags: mysql, macos, mybatis, testcontainers, rancher-desktop

## Problem

I am currently attempting to build a Restful API by using SpringBoot, MyBatis and MySQL.

For testing the MyBatis's Mapper, I use [Testcontainers](https://java.testcontainers.org/) and [Database Rider](https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider).

I wrote the unit test for checking the operation of SQL query for `INSERT` like this:

```java
// entity model class
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ArticleEntity {

    @NonNull
    private final String id;

    @NonNull
    private final String title;

    @NonNull
    private final String body;

    @NonNull
    private final LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @NonNull
    private final LocalDateTime updatedAt;
}
```

```java
// test target class
@Mapper
public interface ArticleEntityMapper {
    
    int insert(ArticleEntity articleEntity);
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">
<mapper namespace="package.of.mapper.ArticleEntityMapper">
    <resultMap id="ArticleEntity" type="package.of.entity.ArticleEntity">
        <constructor>
            <idArg column="id" name="id"/>
            <arg column="title" name="title"/>
            <arg column="body" name="body"/>
            <arg column="created_at" name="createdAt" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler"/>
            <arg column="updated_at" name="updatedAt" typeHandler="org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler"/>
        </constructor>
    </resultMap>
    <insert id="insert">
        INSERT INTO
            articles
        (
            id,
            title,
            body,
            created_at,
            updated_at
        )
        VALUES (
            #{id},
            #{title},
            #{body},
            #{createdAt},
            #{updatedAt}
        )
    </insert>
</mapper>
```

```java
// unit test for target
@DBRider
@MybatisTest
@Testcontainers
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
public class ArticleEntityMapperTest {

    @Autowired
    private ArticleEntityMapper target;

    @Nested
    class InsertTest {

        @Test
        @DataSet("dataset/empty.yml")
        @ExpectedDataSet("dataset/inserted.yml")
        void insert_returnedNumberInserted() {
            // given
            String id = "************************************";
            String title = "Title";
            String body = "Body";
            LocalDateTime createdAt = LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            LocalDateTime updatedAt = LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            ArticleEntity articleEntity = new ArticleEntity(id, title, body, createdAt, updatedAt);
            // when
            int actual = target.insert(articleEntity);
            // then
            assertEquals(1, actual);
        }
    }
```

```yaml
# dataset/empty.yml
articles:
```

```yaml
# dataset/inserted.yml
articles:
  - id: ************************************
    title: Title
    body: Body
    created_at: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    updated_at: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
```

```yaml
# dbunit.yml
properties:
  caseSensitiveTableNames: true
```

```yaml
# application-test.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0:///?TC_INITSCRIPT=file:src/main/resources/schema.sql
    username:
    password:
  test:
    database:
      replace: none
```

When I execute this, the assertion error has occurred (`articles` is table name):

```
row count (table=articles) expected:<[1]> but was:<[0]>
Expected :1
Actual   :0
```

This result means MyBatis thinks the `INSERT` was successful, but the record is not inserted in the actual DB at Docker Container. (because assertion for `actual` is passed)

Please tell me how can I insert a record to DB at Docker Container built by Testcontainers.

## Environment

### Software

- MacBook Pro

  - OS: Ventura 13.4.1
- Docker: 24.0.2-rd
- Rancher Desktop: 1.9.1
- Intellij IDEA 2021.2.4 (Community Edition)
- Gradle: 8.1.1
- Java: openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18 LTS

### Library

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:3.1.0'
    implementation 'org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter:3.0.2'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33'
    implementation "org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0"
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'

    implementation platform('org.testcontainers:testcontainers-bom:1.18.3')
    testImplementation('org.testcontainers:testcontainers')
    testImplementation('org.testcontainers:junit-jupiter')
    testImplementation('org.testcontainers:mysql')
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:3.1.0'
    testImplementation('org.mybatis.spring.boot:mybatis-spring-boot-starter-test:3.0.2')
    testImplementation('com.github.database-rider:rider-junit5:1.38.1')
    testImplementation('commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2')
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.26'
}
```

## Try

### 1. Execute SELECT test

I tried to execute test for `SELECT` query like this:

```java
        @Test
        @DataSet("dataset/selected.yml")
        void entityExists_returnedResult() {
            // given
            String id = "Id";
            // when
            ArticleEntity actual = target.selectById(id);
            // then
            assertEquals("Id", actual.getId());
            assertEquals("Title", actual.getTitle());
            assertEquals("Body", actual.getBody());
            assertEquals(LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), actual.getCreatedAt());
            assertEquals(LocalDateTime.of(1970, 1, 1, 9, 0, 0), actual.getUpdatedAt());
        }
```

This test can be passed and I confirm the record Database rider inserted exists:

```
➜  ~ docker ps | grep mysql
f8a4da7f54b6   mysql:8.0                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   32 seconds ago   Up 29 seconds   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32771->3306/tcp, :::32771->3306/tcp   stupefied_wiles
➜  ~ docker exec -it f8a4da7f54b6 sh
sh-4.4# mysql -u test -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 20
Server version: 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> use test;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select * from articles;
+--------------------------------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id                                   | title | body | created_at          | updated_at          |
+--------------------------------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
| ************************************ | Title | Body | 1970-01-01 09:00:00 | 1970-01-01 09:00:00 |
+--------------------------------------+-------+------+---------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This means the settings of `DataSource` may be correct.

### 2. Check logs of MySQL at Docker Container

When I debug the test for `INSERT` query, I login Docker Container and check logs of MySQL like this:

```
➜  ~ docker ps | grep mysql
4db2a3c6f880   mysql:8.0                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 seconds ago   Up 24 seconds   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32773->3306/tcp, :::32773->3306/tcp   brave_stonebraker
➜  ~ docker exec -it 4db2a3c6f880 sh
sh-4.4# mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 20
Server version: 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2023, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit
Bye
sh-4.4# cat /var/lib/mysql/4db2a3c6f880.log
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 8.0.33 (MySQL Community Server - GPL). started with:
Tcp port: 3306  Unix socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
2023-07-11T16:52:53.160951Z    20 Quit
2023-07-11T16:53:20.510145Z     9 Query SELECT @@session.transaction_read_only
2023-07-11T16:53:20.529118Z     9 Query INSERT INTO
            articles
        (
            id,
            title,
            body,
            created_at,
            updated_at
        )
        VALUES (
            '************************************',
            'Title',
            'Body',
            '1970-01-01 00:00:00',
            '1970-01-01 00:00:00'
        )
```

This result means MySQL received the query but not reflected.

### 3. Execute UPDATE test

I implemented the update method like this:

```xml
    <update id="update">
        UPDATE
            articles
        SET
            title = #{title},
            body = #{body},
            updated_at = #{updatedAt}
        WHERE
            id = #{id}
    </update>
```

Although I wrote and executed test for this, it failed because UPDATE query is not reflected to actual DB like INSERT query.

### 4. Use `@SpringBootTest` (Updated 2023/07/13)

Instead of using `@MyBtisTest`, I tried to use `@SpringBootTest`.

Then **the record is created in actual DB!**

But I don't want to use `@SpringBootTest` for testing mappers because test execution takes too long time.

So I will continue to look for ways to use `@MyBatisTest`.

Comment: Have you tried `@DataSet(transactional=true)`? "In case of `ExpectedDataSet` you’ll usually need a transaction to modify database in order to match expected dataset. In such case you can use a transactional test" https://github.com/database-rider/database-rider#315-transactional-tests

Comment: Thank you for checking my question!
Although I tried to use `@DataSet(transactional=true)`, the result is not changed. (There is no record in actual DB)